# Laravel 5.2 - Auth: display custom error messages

Tags: php, authentication, error-handling, laravel-5

How can I customize the error messages (such as `"These credentials do not match our records."`) that are displayed upon unsuccessful login/registration without having to touch the foundation files? I'm looking for a solution and hopefully an elegant one, at least not touching `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` nor `ThrottlesLogins` :)

I'm using the `AuthController` and forms provided by Laravel after executing:

> php artisan make:auth

**Controller:**

(it only has a constructor and two methods, the rest falls on the foundation, the methods are:)

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

**Form:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
{!! csrf_field() !!}

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Login
        </button>

        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can override `getFailedLoginMessage` on the `AuthController` which comes from the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait

```
protected function getFailedLoginMessage()
{
    return 'what you want here.';
}
```

Or not override it and set a lang value for `auth.failed`. The `getFailedLoginMessage` method will check for `Lang::has('auth.failed')` and use that if its available.

For the actual validation error messages you can override the `postLogin` and pass your own array of messages to `validate`, or if you wanted to change them globally you can adjust them in the appropriate lang file in `resources/lang/{lang}/validation.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lagbox! How about every other error message, "The name field is required." or "The password confirmation does not match." on the user registration form?

Comment: those are the validation messages, you can adjust the authcontroller to pass your own array of messages into the validate call or update those globally in the lang file that they pull from.

Answer (score 8):

You don't want to override the getFailedLoginMessage() method in AuthController. The proper solution is to change the message in the designed location. If you look in the Resources > lang > en folder, you will see an auth.php file. In it, there is a "failed" attribute with a message you can customize. Change it there. The orignial getFailedLoginMessage() method in the Laravel auth files in vendor looks to that location for a custom message first, before settling on the default.

Comment: Thanks Joshua!! :)

Comment: If you update the lang files auth message response then it will update those message replay for other Auth Responses too. The better solution is to override the function and do what you want. If you have multiauth system then other Model which are using AuthenticatesUsers trait will also get the same response as your updation will affect globally.