# laravel 5 auth system: change redirect path and custom error messages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've implemented laravel 5 `auth` system in my project, however i want to some changes in it

**Custom error messages**

1.Now the auth system show only one error message (ie these creditinals do not match our records) ,but  i need to different error messages based on failing login parameters (ie if `email` is invalid it shows invalid email or if user account is disabled it shows account blocked )

**Redirection path**

Conside the situation user is logged in and he is trying to access `login` view again `auth` system redirect to  default route (ie `\`) ,but i need to change this route to user profile (ie `index/dashboard`)

I don't know how to edit the  default `auth` system ,its implemented using traits unfortunately i don't have enough knowledge in traits:(

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure to read the [Authenticating Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-authenticating) .
You can change the Redirect Path within your app/Auth/AuthController. Just set the path with

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

If a User is already authenticated and he goes to the `/login` or `/register` path you can set the Redirect Path in the [RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php#L21)

Just change `return redirect('/');` to your path e.g `return redirect('/dashboard');`

#### Override Auth Trait

If you want to override any Auth Method just take a look at the trait. For example:

If you want to change the view path of the login Method, take a look at the [AuthenticatesUsers trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php). Here you have the [showLoginForm Method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L24-L38). To override this trait just add this Method to your `app/Auth/Authcontroller` and change the view path. e.g

**app/Auth/AuthController**

```
 ....
 ....

/**
 * Override the default trait Method with our own
 */
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $view = property_exists($this, 'loginView')
                ? $this->loginView : 'auth.authenticate';
    if (view()->exists($view)) {
        return view($view);
    }
    return view('myown.path.login'); // Change the View Path
}
```

You can find the Auth Traits in [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth)

#### Custom Error Messages

To make your own custom Error Messages or to change the current Error Messages you should take a look at this [Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750675/laravel-5-2-auth-display-custom-error-messages)

Comment: @bobby sorry for the late reply ,let me try your answer

Comment: One more question I need custom error message based in query failure parameters

Comment: Please read the Links ... 

You can change the Validation Rules in the login method: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L51-L86

This is calling the validation method:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2a38acf7ee2882d831a3b9a1361a710e70ffa31e/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L88-L99