# How to return error with laravel register validator

Tags: php, laravel, registration, laravel-validation

I'm a beginner with laravel.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use ..
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/popin/create_adresse';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:customer'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $this->validator($data);
        return Customer::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my router I have in get 
"Route::get('login', 'PopinController@Login');
 Route::post('register', 'PopinController@PostRegister');"

When I put some valid data, it's working ! But if I put an email who is already store in database, it's returning this exeption `The given data was invalid.`.

How to create a custom error message like "This email is already use by another user !".

I don't understand. 
Thank's for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2 - Auth: display custom error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750675/laravel-5-2-auth-display-custom-error-messages)

Comment: unique:customer or customers??

Comment: @A.ANoman yes my table name is customer.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini No, because i'm not using AuthController, I don't have it. This project is not my own and I don"t have the real history..

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve errors use this:

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:customer'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $validator->errors();
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $errors = $this->validator($data);
     ...
```

It will return the list or errors you need

Comment: It's returning this LOG.error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\MessageBag::validate()..

Comment: you have to add `use Validator;` in use section

Comment: I already use this "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;" and it's not working with "use Validator;" to..

Comment: which version of Laravel do you use? And share please the whole controller file

Comment: I have uptdate the question